# drawRect: being called, only shows the frame not the drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect, uibezierpath

I have a `UIControl` subclass where I have `drawRect` implemented.  I am trying to draw a rectangle inside of the `drawRect` method using a `UIBezierPath`.  All the appropriate methods are being called, nothing is null and the app runs with no issues.  The problem is, nothing but the frame is drawn.  Meaning, I can see the area of the frame, because it is black, but I cannot see anything that was drawn onto the frame.

Here is what I am doing to instantiate the class:

```
ZHButton *button =
    [[ZHButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 50)];
button.buttonType = NSSelectorFromString(LEFT_ROUNDED_CORNER_BUTTON);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Here is the drawRect: method, which calls different methods using a selector:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *button = [self performSelector:self.buttonType withObject:nil];
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [button fill];
}

- (UIBezierPath *)drawButtonWithLeftCornersRounded {
        return [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.frame
                                     byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft |
                                                       UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                                           cornerRadii:buttonRadii];
}
```

Everything appears to be working fine, but the `UIBezierPath` does not get drawn.  Also, not sure if using a selector is the best way to do this.  Anyone know what is going on with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  In `drawButtonWithLeftCornersRounded` `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` should not be `self.frame`.  This will cause the x and y coordinates to be at the x, y location within the frame, not the view.  I changed it the parameter to this:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not calling the `drawButtonWithLeftCornersRounded` method. I believe this line is wrong:

```
[self performSelector:self.buttonType withObject:nil];
```

But it should be:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(drawButtonWithLeftCornersRounded) withObject:nil];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: drawButtonWithLeftCornersRounded is being called.  self.buttonType is a selector. I tried your change, it had the same results.